# How to implement business-specific rules to IdentityServer4 pipeline?

Tags: c#, identityserver4

Disclaimer: I am pretty new to IdentityServer4 and have little knowledge of Authentication processes in general.

On my project, we have an ASP.NET Core WebAPI which uses Jwt Berarer tokens for authentication.

These tokens are issued by the client (iOS app) to another API we have (auth api), which uses IdentityServer4.

A new requisite came in, in which we now should prevent users from using our client app (iOS app) when outside of business hours.

First, I need to know who should be responsible of implementing such rule, then how to implement it.

I have already played a little with `ICustomTokenRequestValidator` interface, and managed to insert my custom `BusinessHoursTokenRequestValidator` into the pipeline, but I am not even sure this is what I should be doing.

My custom validator:

```cs
public class BusinessHoursTokenRequestValidator : ICustomTokenRequestValidator
{
    public async Task ValidateAsync(CustomTokenRequestValidationContext context)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var endOfBusinessHours = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 18, 0, 0);

        if (now > endOfBusinessHours)
        {
            context.Result.IsError = true;
            context.Result.Error = "ERROR 001";
            context.Result.ErrorDescription = "Access time restricted to business hours only.";
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

AuthAPI Startup.cs:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // configurations ommited for brevity

    services.AddIdentityServer(options => 
    {
        // ommited for brevity
    })
    .AddManyMoreOtherConfigurations()
    .AddCustomTokenRequestValidator<BusinessHoursTokenRequestValidator>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The business hour requirement is an authorization requirement and not an authentication requirement. IdentityServer is all about authentication, so the natural place to put the rule about time is in the application itself. So, just let IdentityServer handles the authentication (who the user is) and deal with the authorization locally is the easiest.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It makes sense. I have read before about the differences of authentication vs authorization, but I did not know IdentityServer4 was all about authentication.

Comment: I visited their website after reading your response, and it seems they claim to have solutions for authorization features as well. At https://identityserver.io/

Comment: Yes, they do have PolicyServer as an optional addon for this. But in your case just limiting for time, I would recomend that you do it all in the application level, not in IdentityServer. The issue is also how to handle users who are already logged in? and already issued tokens?